# GIF ответ сервера

Tags: responsive, google-analytics, yandex-metrika-api, gif

Заметил, что Яндекс.Метрика (да и Google Analytics тоже) отвечает сайту `gif изображением 1x1 px` (?!). Что это такое? "Трюк" с `html`?

**Запрос**

```
GET /webvisor/32138055?rn=680591080... HTTP/1.1
Host: mc.yandex.ru
User-Agent: someua
Cookie: somecookie
```

**Ответ**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 43
Connection: keep-alive
```

**некоторые заголовки убрал специально*

Длина ответа данных `43b`? Но ответ пуст!(или заполнен пробелами?!). Прошу объяснить, что это такое.

Answer (score 0):

Тут выполняется задача отправки данных, а получать ответ необходимости нет. При запросе gif изображения, сервер сбора статистики получает все необходимые данные. Страницу, на которой размещено изображение и другие данные, например, версию браузера, cookie. 
Кстати, с помощью загрузки пустого gif, можно отправлять данные на сервер (кросс-доменный запрос), некоторые параметры безопасности могут ограничивать отправку данных на сторонние адреса. Загрузку картинки же никто не будет ограничивать.